# Update Azure API management ip-filter policy details

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-cli, ibm-api-management

I have created an API Management resource in Azure. Within the API management, under APIs section > All APIs, I have added an inbound policy 'ip-filter'.

[image]

**I wish to programatically change the contents of the policy's xml.**

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Set-AzApiManagementPolicy` from the Az Powershell to set the Policy XML.

```
Set-AzApiManagementPolicy -Context $apimContext -PolicyFilePath "C:\contoso\policies\tenantpolicy.xml"
```

There are various scopes. You could set it at the tenant level,product level,api level and at the operation level. You could [refer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.apimanagement/set-azurermapimanagementpolicy?view=azurermps-6.13.0) this for more information.

Comment: Please consider accepting this solution if it had helped :)
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work